# Why is there an alarm clock badge on the YouTube app?

Tags: applications, ios

I’m using iOS 11 public beta 1 and today I’ve noticed an alarm clock badge on the YouTube app. Now I’m wondering why it is there and what does it mean?

[image]

Right now the badge is just a normal red circle with a 1 inside.

**Update**

It also showed me this:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The icon is telling you *why* Siri is suggesting the app to you by placing it in the Dock. Siri's proactive abilities means it suggests apps it thinks you are likely to use for a variety of reasons:

- Alarm icon: app suggested because of the time of day
- ‘Location’ arrow: app suggested because of your current location

You can disable apps from being suggested on the Dock by going to Settings → General → Multitasking & Dock and disabling Show Suggested and Recent Apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have also official information what those badges mean? Is there a list of all the different badges?